# SQL Query with Include and Exclude

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query where i search a table SYSTEMS and i want it to show me all accounts that have SYSTEM.TYPE = 'WIFI' but no SYSTEM.TYPE = 'SENSOR'.  Trying to query clients with a specific controller but no add on equipment so we can market them?  Note the clients may have additional SYSTEM.TYPES that are useless to query but would be present.

USING SQL Manager, using current Query but the results are giving me the wrong answers, an example is a table called systems where each system is logged with fields acct_no and type.  I want all acct_no  where 'type' = WIFI but there is no 'type' = FLOW.

```
SELECT S.ACCT_NO, s.[type] 
FROM [system] S 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [system] FS 
  on FS.acct_no = S.acct_no
WHERE not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM [system] 
                  WHERE [system].ACCT_NO = fs.ACCT_NO 
                    AND FS.[TYPE] in ('flow sensor', 'sprinkler', 'lighting'))
  AND (s.[type] like '%wifi%')
```

Comment: Your question must show that you've made an attempt at figuring this out on your own before coming here to ask. Also, it's very unclear - I'm not exactly sure what you're even asking. If you just included a `WHERE SYSTEM.TYPE = 'WIFI'`, would that not be enough to eliminate all other types...?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: I need accounts with TYPE = WIFI but TYPE <> FLOW

Comment: SELECT ACCT_NO FROM [system] 
WHERE (([type] like '%wifi%')
  AND  NOT ([type] in ('flow sensor', 'sprinkler', 'lighting')))
  order by ACCT_NO

Comment: Not getting proper results, still showing me accounts with WIFI and FLOW

Comment: Using Sql Server Management Studio

Comment: You need to edit your question and add all this information instead of posting comments. Also, a table structure and data sample are needed to help you. Do you have more than one row per type? does your type have a list of values?

Comment: Why do you need the left join? if you eliminate it and simply correlate the subquery as @EricZ did you should get what i think you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for? My understanding is you have multiple records per ACCT_NO with different TYPE

```
SELECT s1.ACCT_NO 
FROM [system]  s1
WHERE s1.[type] like '%wifi%'
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM [system] s2 
     WHERE s1.ACCT_NO = s2.ACCT_NO 
       AND s2.[type] in ('flow sensor', 'sprinkler', 'lighting')) 
ORDER BY ACCT_NO
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it.

```
SELECT Distinct s1.ACCT_NO 
FROM [system]  s1
WHERE s1.[type] like '%wifi%'
EXCEPT
SELECT Distinct s2.ACCT_NO  
FROM [system] s2 
WHERE s2.[type] in ('flow sensor', 'sprinkler', 'lighting')
```

select all the account numbers that have a type wifi.
except the accounts that have a type 'flow sensor', 'sprinkler' or 'lighting'

Answer (score -2):

Is TYPE a column name in Systems table? If so, you can try this query:

```
select * 
from SYSTEMS 
where (SYSTEMS.TYPE='WIFI' and SYSTEMS.TYPE!='SENSOR');
```

Comment: i got an error on your code: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '`'.

Comment: for a single record a type couldn't be WIFI and sensor.  Each account could be listed multiple times in the system table and thus have multiple records each with different types.